# Trim TextView in the middle, reserving ending characters

Tags: android, textview

I'm struggling with textview overlapping problem. I have two textviews side by side

```
asd1234 | september 1
```

If the left textview is appended with more characters("567") the result is

```
asd…23{lost chars} | september 1
```

The desired result would be

```
asd…567 | september 1
```

My textview attributes are

```
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

Is there any way to make it work with attributes, or do I have to trim the string programatically? What is the correct way to do it? Thanks

**EDIT**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/date"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are the "lost chars" scrolled off the right side of the text field? Where is the caret/selection after appending "567"? You can control these things. Are the "lost chars" covered by the other text field? In that case your layout needs fixing, eg put the two into a horizontal layout.

Comment: _lost chars_ are covered by the `date` textview. Changing the parent layout to `linearlayout` didn't affect the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few changes in your xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/date"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="I have wrote some longestttt text over here for testing the ellipsize"
        android:textColor="#fff" 
        android:ellipsize="middle"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="02-09-2014"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Mainly, changed `maxLines = 1` to `singleLine = true`, which made difference. As till then I didn't get the proper output:

This gives me output as:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont think so this is problem

Comment: @PratikButani OP has written: The desired result would be `asd…567 | september 1` with ellipsis applied in middle.

Comment: @Dhruti Thanks, I'll try your solution as soon as I get to my computer

Comment: I have the same issue but I cannot apply the solution provided because I need to have 2 lines max, not a single line. Still need to have my string trimmed in the middle if overflow and take one line space if it takes less than 2 lines. Any suggestions @MysticMagicϡ